# C# - SendInput() from Windows Service not working but returns 1 - Win03

Tags: c#, windows-services, sendinput

This is a somewhat unusual problem. I'm presently working on an effort to automate an Office application. Basically the issue is that my app is able to interact with the Office app correctly when I execute my app via RDP, but I am unable to send keystrokes using SendInput() if I set up the application to spawn from a windows service. OS is Win03 Std.

When spawning the app from a windows service I'm able to read window captions, automate through the interop, etc. as expected via pinvoke, but the SendInput() messages seemingly vanish even though the call returns a 1. All I'm trying to do at this point is send an escape keystroke to a dialog.

I've tried sending the keystrokes both as virtual keys and scancodes.

Any ideas or tips? Thanks in advance!

(BTW: I do realize that this sort of automation isn't supported/sanctioned by MSFT.)

**EDIT:** 
Just in case anyone else has this issue, this works:

```
[DllImport("user32")]

public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


bool returnVal = NativeWin32.PostMessage(popup, 0x0100, new IntPtr(0x1b), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that SendInput will send keys to current active window (or window that has focus). Typically, windows services would be associated with different desktop (that interactive desktop) - so App launched from windows service would also be associated with the background desktop - so no active window (or window with focus) and that's may be the reason sendinout not working. You can perhaps try simulating key click by using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` - you will need window handle for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help; for some reason I totally blew past the fact that there's no window that's able to receive focus. *grumble* I'm testing with PostMessage now.

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows Vista, services are no longer allowed to interact with the desktop. Which means they would not have a desktop context to send keyboard events to.