# How to set focus on "Untitled - Notepad" using windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I want to set focus on notepad (Untitled - Notepad) and write some text into it. I have to create a Windows Service for this.

I can create windows service but don't know how to set focus on notepad.

Please provide me code samples in Windows Service

I have tried following code. But no luck with it.

```
namespace SampleService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        string application = string.Empty;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        GetTaskWindows();
        int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, application);

        NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        GetTaskWindows();
        int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, application);

        NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
    }


    private void GetTaskWindows()
    {
        // Get the desktopwindow handle
        int nDeshWndHandle = NativeWin32.GetDesktopWindow();
        // Get the first child window
        int nChildHandle = NativeWin32.GetWindow(nDeshWndHandle, NativeWin32.GW_CHILD);

        while (nChildHandle != 0)
        {
            // Get only visible windows
            if (NativeWin32.IsWindowVisible(nChildHandle) != 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sbTitle = new StringBuilder(1024);
                // Read the Title bar text on the windows to put in combobox
                NativeWin32.GetWindowText(nChildHandle, sbTitle, sbTitle.Capacity);
                String sWinTitle = sbTitle.ToString();
                {
                    if (sWinTitle.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (sWinTitle.Contains("Notepad"))
                        {
                            application = sWinTitle;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Look for the next child.
            nChildHandle = NativeWin32.GetWindow(nChildHandle, NativeWin32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show some code what you trying

Comment: have you tried googling it?

Comment: Interacting with the desktop from a windows service is not supported on the latest versions of Windows. Why do you want to do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242909/c-sharp-sendinput-from-windows-service-not-working-but-returns-1-win03

Comment: Added code which I am using to my question.

Comment: As already stated, interacting with the desktop from a service is not really supported. After all, which desktop should you get (if there are multiple users logged onto the machine)? You haven't detailed your requirements, but the standard approach would probably be to implement this using a tray application that runs at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself. Created one small application which will focus on notepad and used sendKeys function to write text into notepad.